# Prototype find element and only perform if found

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, undefined

Struggling a little here with prototype = I've created this function

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

if ($$('#test li:first')!=null) {
   $('test').down('li').down('a').update('Test');
}
});
```

Basically, it works on pages where #test li:first is found but on pages it isn't it returns

```
$("test").down("li") is undefined
```

I just wanted it to basically work only if it found the element otherwise not work ?

**Edit: Solved**

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

try { 

if ($$('#test li:first')!=null) {
   $('test').down('li').down('a').update('Test');
} } 

catch(ex) {
}

});
```

Comment: Wrap it in a try / catch block.

Comment: hey thanks :) not really sure on prototype - are you able to help out with a sample ? :)

Answer (score 4):

That's not really solving it; you are just catching an error that is easily fixed.

Try this on for size:

```
$$('#test li:first-child').invoke('update', 'Test');
```